# Join computer behind 2nd router to the rest of the LAN

Tags: networking

My LAN got a little complicated with the addition of a VoIP router recently.

`Main Router` (192.168.1.x) =>
 * `Computer 1`
 * `Computer 2`
 * `Computer 3`
 * `OBi302 VoIP Router` (192.168.10.x) => `Computer 4`

I'd like to be able to communicate from the main network to `Computer 4`. The only thing I could think of was a VPN tunnel to the main router from `Computer 4`. Would this work and is it the best way to go?

NOTE: I do not know the login info for the VoIP router, and it's leased, so not sure they'd give it to me if I asked. So no DMZ or Port Forwarding is going to be possible on that device.

Edit to answer some questions below:

There's only one network drop @ `Computer 4`, so I put the VoIP router in between the computer and the main router, as I tried to show in the text diagram above.

I could probably add another NIC to the PC and share internet to the VoIP router through that, but I think a VPN connection might be simpler.

The VoIP router is an OBi302 leased by PhonePower. I don't know login details for it. admin:admin doesn't work.

Edit 2: That computer uses very little traffic so QoS isn't an issue.

Comment: You have us to give a bit more information. What kind of VoIP Router? What interfaces? Can it be configured? If it is connected by two ethernet interfaces to (1) the Main Router and (2) Computer 4, why don't you connect Computer 4 directly to the Main Router? Can you install a second ethernet port on Computer 4?

Comment: Only one network drop? Buy a cheap 4-port switch. (Like the one that's embededded into the first router.)

Comment: Alternatively, assuming you don't need gig speeds, just split the network drop into 2 by using a port splitter.  You can run 2 ethernet connections over a single 8 core twisted pair.

Comment: Does computer 4 benefit from being behind the VOIP router ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Buy a cheap switch. (That's how the main router provides you with multiple ports already.)

---

Option 2: Set up routing.

First, find out the VoIP router's "WAN" IP address – that is, the `192.168.1.x` one. (It's going to have two IP addresses, just like the main router does: one for the 'inside', one for the 'outside'.)

Then tell the main router where `192.168.10.x` is. If it has a "static routes" configuration page, add the following route:

```
NETWORK             NETMASK         GATEWAY
192.168.10.0 / 24   255.255.255.0   192.168.1.x
```

The *gateway* here needs to be the VoIP router's "external" (192.168.1.x) address. This will work as long as the VoIP router does not firewall connections coming from its 'outside'.

Comment: This would only work if the VOIP router is not doing NAT - and it almost certainly will be.  I don't think a cheap switch is the answer - I assume the computer is behind the VOIP router so it can do QoS.   My take could be wrong though.

Comment: No, it works perfectly fine with NAT. Such "many to one" NAT setups are one-way: as long as the _firewall_ permits an incoming connection, the NAT will not prevent it; it only translates packets associated to outgoing ones.

Comment: It could work for the outgoing requests from Computer 4, but not requests going into computer 4.  (In Linux, which most consumer routers are built on, the Firewalling is done in the "Forward" chain, while NAT is done in the POSTROUTING chain).  That said, after pulling up the specs for the device, I see that this thing is not so much a router as an ATA with minimal routing functionality for 1 port - so I agree that a cheap switch on the WAN interface side is the way to go.

Comment: Would've installed a little switch already if all the spots on the battery backup side of the UPS weren't already filled to keep the phone line up during frequent power outages.

Comment: Static Route is working. Thanks for the help. Exactly the sort of solution I was hoping existed.  http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1474239258.png

Comment: Could you post output of "ifconfig; route -n" - I wonder if the the ethernet ports on the OBi302 are bridged ?

Comment: Sure. From Computer 4 I get: http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1474239813.png

Comment: @davidgo: Funny, I've done this exact same configuration to dig through several Linux-based and even FreeBSD-based routers here. Request comes in, is allowed by FORWARD, gets routed directly to the inner host with no NAT. (It doesn't _need_ NAT to work, since the origin already knows how to reach the inner addresses, so the situation reduces to ordinary IP routing.)

Comment: (The ICMP "Redirect" shows up because the main router knows that the origin and the gateway are on the same subnet, so it offers the origin to add the same route on _itself_ to avoid indirection. That would also work, but it would have to be done on every host rather at a central place.)

Answer (score 1):

A VPN on Computer 4 could work, and may be the best available solution (short of changing hardware)

Another alternative might be to change the netmask for 192.168.1.x to 192.168.x.x), then, leaving computer4 on its current IP and gateway - and  change its netmask to 192.168.x.x and run a cable between the LAN interfaces of each router.   In this way local traffic should run directly to computer 4, while non-local - ie Internet traffic would be routed through the VOIP router.    THIS WILL ONLY WORK IF DHCP IS DISABLED ON THE VOIP ROUTER THOUGH, and will make debugging network issues that much harder as this would be very non-standard.

Comment: Would've been cool to try but I can't get into the router to turn off DHCP.

Comment: @leetwanker - a small power strip, & small switch would be a better option, unless your battery backup is under powered. Most VOIP providers tell you to put the VOIP in front of your main router, because of problems with firewalls in front of VOIP blocking UDP or causing jitter for it. So, behind your 1st router, you should have set a static DHCP entry for it, & should've put that IP into your 1st router as DMZ.  Thus, machine 4 is now vulnerable to anything the VOIP passes through as not destined for "itself" dmz by proxy. If you haven't put VOIP in as DMZ, you may have problems maybe not.

Comment: @TG2 Won't having the VoIP router out front possibly interfere with port forwards and such? I know some routers have a bad time when passing a lot of traffic, also.

Comment: @leetwanker - if not defined in the VOIP box, yes.  Most (if not all) VOIP soho units are designed RTR/GW/FW.. but for many of us (self incl'd) we're not about to use an el--cheap-o SPA2102 or similar as our home GW/FW, that's why we've paid serious dollars for generation X 1900AC gig routers :) The reasoning VOIP wants to be up front, is the sensitivity of voice to jitter and other effects, and that most firewalls don't like unknown source traffic and udp streams, which sip/voip seems to have in abundance. Most situations if you're putting it behind your FW, it must be in/as the DMZ device.

Comment: & comment of "if you haven't already" gotten to VOIP device as the IP for DMZ traffic, problems  vary depending on how good your ISP is about getting packets to your door.  Comcast in my area is good, but not great, so I still had to work with Broadvoice, to shift my assigned servers around to get one (or a set) that are better reached from comcast ... took trial & error.  For me, the last time was a little over a year ago when their systems were merging something with PhonePower and they sent out new non-optimal settings again.

Comment: So far the VoIP router seems to be working fine without being out front. I haven't received any complaints anyway. I'll consider putting it in the DMZ if it starts to have problems but opening up a hole in my network like that scares me a bit. Thanks for all the advice!